# How to use NTP on Raspberry Pi by local NTP server

Tags: raspbian, ntp

I have Raspberry Pi Model-B with the [Raspbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian) Wheezy OS and a local NTP server. I want to synchronise my Raspberry Pi board with my local NTP server (not using the Internet). All the process must be offline, not using the Internet. What is the 
step-by-step process to do this?

Comment: I think you just add your server to /etc/ntp.conf

Comment: thanks for reply
how can i add my server ip ?

Answer (score 3):

> This answer is OBSOLETE. Debian 9 uses `systemd-timesyncd.service`

In `/etc/ntpd.conf`, replace the existing "server" entries with one for your server.   You can use the hostname or IP address of your server.

For example:

```
server  192.168.1.15
```

After changing the file,

```
sudo service ntp restart
```

will restart the NTP daemon using your updated configuration.

Use

```
$ sudo ntpq
ntpq> peers
```

to verify that it's using your host as a peer. If everything is working, you should see non-zero values in the "when" and "reach" columns.