# Get time using NTP from LAN PC

Tags: networking, ntp

For my application, the Raspberry Pi is not connected to the Internet. Instead, it communicates to my PC via a direct ethernet connection. The PC is a Windows 7 desktop PC which is NOT connected to the internet when talking to the Pi, but maintains its own time clock, like all desktop machines.
Since the Pi is unable to get time from the NTP servers over the internet, I need a workaround to get time to the Pi.  How should I do that? I'm thinking the Desktop could be an NTP server and the Pi could ping that.

[How to use NTP on Raspberry Pi by local NTP server](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/how-to-use-ntp-on-raspberry-pi-by-local-ntp-server) post mentions how to configure the Pi to get time from a local NTP server.
How do I set up a local NTP server on my Windows PC, and is it even possible to do since it's not connected to the internet while it talks to the Pi?

Comment: It looks like this may be what you need:

http://www.satsignal.eu/ntp/setup.html

Comment: "How to set up an NTP server on Windows" would be more appropriate to [Super User](http://superuser.com/).   Don't refer to the pi as that is an irrelevant aspect of a larger story.