# How to set custom NTP servers in recent raspbian (Stretch) systems?

Tags: systemd, ntp

How do I set the NTP server setting to a custom value in recent versions of Raspbian? I've noticed in a Stretch image that /etc/ntpd.conf does not exist in the default full image, nor is ntpd process running or even installed, yet when on an Internet-connected network, the system time does get set at or soon after system boot.

I'm primarily interested in if and how raspbian supports this by default (if it does), rather than how I can modify it outside of typical administrative actions.

My question is very similar to this question: ["How to use NTP on Raspberry Pi by local NTP server"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/how-to-use-ntp-on-raspberry-pi-by-local-ntp-server) But the only answer (which refers to /etc/ntpd.conf) has a disclaimer that says "This answer is OBSOLETE. Debian 9 uses `systemd-timesyncd.service`."

So I guess a better way to phrase this question is, how do I set custom local NTP servers for `systemd-timesyncd.service`?

Comment: Stretch uses a different NTP implementation than prior versions: https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/ So what you will find is `chronyd`, not `ntpd`.

Comment: Are you sure? Stretch seems to use systemd-timesyncd, https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/24087/44943 I cannot find chronyd on Stretch 4.14.71-v7+ #1145

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit  `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` , especially the second line

```
[Time]
NTP=your.servername.goes.here
FallbackNTP=0.arch.pool.ntp.org 1.arch.pool.ntp.org 2.arch.pool.ntp.org 3.arch.pool.ntp.org
#RootDistanceMaxSec=5
#PollIntervalMinSec=32
#PollIntervalMaxSec=2048
```